# Transmission of values between a inner class and outer class

Tags: java, gwt

I am struggling a long time now with the following problem:
I do not understand why the method setStatus () does not work. The method setButton () check whether the individual elements in a field "status" to "true" if all this have to activate a button. Unfortunately staus field values ​​do not change.

I'd like to add, that textBox.setTitle() and textBox.addStyleName work well.

Here is my code:

```
package com.mg;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.comarch.spr.client.UserServlet;
import com.comarch.spr.client.UserServletAsync;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.BlurEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.BlurHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;

public class Validator {

    private ArrayList<ValidationElement> listOfElements = new ArrayList<Validator.ValidationElement>();
    private Button button;
    public int i = 0;

    public Validator(ArrayList<ValidationElement> listOfElements, Button button) {
        this.listOfElements = listOfElements;
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void createElement0(TextBox textbox, String regex, int type, UserServletAsync userServlet ) {
        ValidationElement element = new ValidationElement(textbox, regex, type, userServlet);
        listOfElements.add(element);
    }

    public void createElement1(TextBox textbox, String regex, int type ) {
        ValidationElement element = new ValidationElement(textbox, regex, type);
        listOfElements.add(element);
    }

    public void addElement(ValidationElement element) {
        listOfElements.add(element);
    }

    public void setButton() {
        int sizeOfList = listOfElements.size();
        int check = 0;
        for(ValidationElement element : listOfElements) {
            element.validate();
            if (element.status == true)
                check = check + 1;
        }
        if (check != 0) 
            button.setEnabled(true);
        else 
            button.setEnabled(false);
    }

    //========================== VALIDATION ELEMENT CLASS===========================
    public class ValidationElement {
        public TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        public boolean status;
        public String regex;
        public int type;            // 0 - validateFromDatabase() , || 1 - checkRegEx()
        public UserServletAsync userServlet;

        public ValidationElement(TextBox textbox, String regex, int type ) {
            this.textBox = textbox;
            this.regex = regex;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ValidationElement(TextBox textbox, String regex, int type, UserServletAsync userServlet) {
            this.textBox = textbox;
            this.regex = regex;
            this.type = type;
            this.userServlet = userServlet;
        }


        public boolean isStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(boolean status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        //========================== VALIDATION FUNCTIONS ========================================= 

        public void validate() {
            if (type == 0) {
                validateFromDatabase();
            }
            else if(type == 1)
                checkRegEx();
        }
        public void validateFromDatabase() {
            textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
                    final String text = textBox.getText();
                    userServlet.validateUser(textBox.getText(), new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        }
                        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                            boolean resultOfCallback = result;  
                            if(resultOfCallback){
                                textBox.addStyleName("invalid");
                                textBox.setTitle("error");
                            }
                            else if (text.matches(regex) && !resultOfCallback) {
                                textBox.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                                setStatus(true);
                            }
                            else if (text.matches(regex) && resultOfCallback) {
                            }
                            else {
                                textBox.addStyleName("invalid");
                                textBox.setTitle("error");
                                }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        }
        public void checkRegEx () {
            textBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                    final String text = textBox.getText();
                    if(!text.matches(regex))
                    {
                        setStatus(false);
                    }
                    else { 
                        setStatus(true);
                    }
                    isValid();
                }   
            });
            textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

                    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
                    final String text = textBox.getText();
                        if(!text.matches(regex))
                            {
                        textBox.addStyleName("invalid");
                        textBox.setTitle("error");
                        setStatus(false);
                            }
                        else 
                        {
                        setStatus(true);
                        textBox.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                        textBox.setTitle("error");
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
        public void isValid() {
            if(this.status = true)
                i=i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void isValid() {
        if(this.status = true)
            i=i+1;
    }
```

Shouldn't this be

```
   public void isValid() {
        if(this.status == true) 
            i=i+1;
    }
```

The first method **sets** the status to true, then always increments `i`.

Or you can go one better:

```
   public void isValid() {
        if(this.status) {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Also if you're using Eclipse, you can set the compiler options to highlight accidental boolean assignments in `if` statements as compilation errors. It's a very useful option.

Comment: isValid is not an important function. This remnant of the old code. My problem is better described in the following response.

Comment: Important or not, it is called from your regex validator. And your database validator never seems to set status to false either.

Answer (score 0):

In class Validator, there is:

```
    public int i = 0;
```

In class ValidationElement, which is inside Validator, in for example checkRegEx() method, I put: 
i++;

```
public void checkRegEx () {
    textBox.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
            final String text = textBox.getText();
            if(!text.matches(regex))
            {
                setStatus(false);
            }
            else { 
                setStatus(true);
            }
            isValid();
        }   
    });
    textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

            public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
            final String text = textBox.getText();
                if(!text.matches(regex))
                    {
                textBox.addStyleName("invalid");
                textBox.setTitle("error");
                setStatus(false);
                    }
                else 
                {
                textBox.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                textBox.setTitle("ok");
                i++;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

When I want to see if everything is okay. It turns out that the value of "i" in setButton() method in class Validator is still zero, while the other lines of code in this block work well:

```
                textBox.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                textBox.setTitle("ok");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's just *too early* to check `status` at the next line after `validate()` is invoked.

As far as I can tell status changes only after `BlurEvent` happens. TextBox updates you mention work fine because these seem to be triggered at the right moment.

```
public void setButton() {
    int sizeOfList = listOfElements.size();
    int check = 0;
    button.setEnabled(false); // reset button
    for(ValidationElement element : listOfElements) {
        element.validate();
        // drop attempt to check status here
    }
    // drop attempt to enable button here
}
//...
                    {
                    button.setEnabled(true); // was: setStatus(true);
                    textBox.setStyleName("gwt-TextBox");
                    textBox.setTitle("error");
                    }
```

Also I would prefer to define `ValidationElement`
 static:

```
public static class ValidationElement
    // have quite a painful experience chasing subtle bugs
    // related to named non-static inner classes
```